# how to create a rank based on previous period performance using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset looks like the followings. I want to rank each name based on his previous day's performance. If the `sales` of `name` is ranked as top 10% (20%) on day t, then rank for `name` on day t+1 should be 1 (2). Similarly,if the `sales` of `name` is ranked as bottom 10% on day t, then rank for `name` on day t+1 should be 10.

```
name   date   sales   rank
a      day1     11
b      day1     20
c      day1     15
d      day1     8
a      day2     12 
b      day2     21
c      day2     16
d      day2     9
a      day3     7 
b      day3     14
c      day3     12
d      day3     10
```

what I did so far is:
step 1. sort data by `date` `sales`
step 2. create new_variable `i` and `N`. I is the exact ranking of name i on each `date`. `N` measure the total number of observation on each `date`. if `I`/`N` is less than .1, then `Rank_previous` = 10, et al. This new variable `Rank_previous` will be the ranking of `name` on day t.

However, I dont know how to assign today's ranking `Rank_previous` to the following day as `Rank`. Because, my dataset is quite big, it will be great if you have more efficient way to solve this problem.

```
data data;
    set data;
    retain I;by date sales;
    if first.date or first.sales then I=1; else I=I+1;
run;
proc sql;
    create table data
    as select a.*,  max(I) as N 
    from data as a  
    group by date sales
    order by date sales;
quit;

data data (drop=I N);
    set data;
    Rank_temp = I/N; 
    if Rank_temp <= .1 then rank = 10;
run;
```

Comment: Please be precise on the size of your dataset.

Comment: If sales person b was on holiday yesterday, does this person have a rank of 0 today?

Comment: Thanks for your question. the dataset is about 2GB   If company is missing yesterday, its rank should be 0 or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** First let us load a little more data than in the example: **;

```
data have;
input name   $ date   $ sales;
datalines;
a      day1     11
b      day1     20
c      day1     15
d      day1     8
a      day2     12 
b      day2     21
c      day2     16
d      day2     9
e      day2     1
f      day2     90
g      day2     99
h      day2     2
i      day2     70
j      day2     39
k      day2     1
l      day2     16
m      day2     90
a      day3     7 
b      day3     14
c      day3     12
d      day3     10
e      day4     1
f      day4     90
g      day4     99
h      day4     2
i      day4     70
j      day4     39
k      day4     1
l      day4     16
m      day4     90
;
run;
```

** Then, as Joe taught us, let us apply proc rank. We will need the rank, not the sales, so let us get rid of it **;

```
proc rank  groups=10
    data=have 
    out=ranks  (drop=sales);

    by date;
    var sales;
    ranks rank_previous;
run;
```

** Now to merge the rank of the previous day with the sales of today, we need a little memery **;

```
data have_memory;
    set have;
    by date;

    retain date_previous;
    if first.date then date_previous = lag1(date);
run;
```

** Now a classical merge does the job **;

```
data have_ranked (drop=date_previous);
    merge have_memory (in=has)
          ranks (rename=(date=date_previous));
    by date_previous name;

    if not has then date = 'next';
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to compute ranks is, unsurprisingly given SAS's nomenclature, [`PROC RANK`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146840.htm).  For this, data must be sorted `by date` first.

```
data have;
input name   $ date   $ sales;
datalines;
a      day1     11
b      day1     20
c      day1     15
d      day1     8
a      day2     12 
b      day2     21
c      day2     16
d      day2     9
a      day3     7 
b      day3     14
c      day3     12
d      day3     10
;;;;
run;

proc rank data=have out=ranks percent;
by date;
var sales;
ranks rank;
run;
```

The `percent` argument asks for percentiles and not numeric ranks.  Another option that might give you the rank you want is `groups=10` which would assign all values to one of ten groups, though sometimes it's easier to use the raw percentile and assign on your own (to better handle ties and such).  You also can use `descending` to assign in reverse order, as it's unclear to me what order you intend.

Of course, as you want the rank on the *next* day, you will then need to have a short datastep to increment date by one and merge back on, or a SQL join, or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 sets of temporary ARRAYs: One to hold the rankings of the previous day and one to create the rankings for the current day.

When you hit the LAST.date for the current day, you can OUTPUT all the information for the current day, including the previous days rankings. Then, copy today's rankings to the previous day's array.

This way, you only have to go through your data one time after it's been sorted by date and sales.

Answer (score 1):

First let us load a little more data than in the example:

```
data have;
input name   $ date   $ sales;
datalines;
a      day1     11
b      day1     20
c      day1     15
d      day1     8
a      day2     12 
b      day2     21
c      day2     16
d      day2     9
e      day2     1
f      day2     90
g      day2     99
h      day2     2
i      day2     70
j      day2     39
k      day2     1
l      day2     16
m      day2     90
a      day3     7 
b      day3     14
c      day3     12
d      day3     10
;
run;
```

As performance matters, I would go for PROC MEAN (which is an extended versoin of proc sort that can keep subtotals and is extremely efficient. The class clause corresponds to the by clause in proc sort)

```
proc means data=have noprint;
class date sales name;
output out=haveMean (where=(_type_ in (4,7)));
```

Subtotals and details are destinguished by *type*. Leave out the where clause to find out which type has what data. 
Now merge *type* 4: from which *freq* gives us the number of sales personel active on that day and *type* 7: the detailed information

```
data salesSum;
merge haveMean (where=(_type_ eq 4) rename=(_freq_=numberPerDay) drop=name sales)
      haveMean (where=(_type_ eq 7));
by date;
```

Keep track of the order number within the day to divide it by the nr of sales persons active

```
retain orderInDay rank;
if first.date then orderInDay = 1; else orderInDay = orderInDay+ 1;
```

Only calculate the rank for the first observation with a certain sales volume give exequos the same rank

```
if first.date or lag1(sales) NE sales then rank = ceil(10 * orderInDay / numberPerDay);
```

Print what is relevant

```
proc print data=salesSum;
by date;
var name sales rank;
run;
```

This solution still misses a way to port the ranking to the next working day. I consider using a hash table to that end.

Comment: I don't think `PROC MEANS` has anything to do with `PROC SORT`, but it's an interesting comparison.  `PROC MEANS` accumulates through an AVL tree, roughly similar to the data step hash object; `class` variables are subtly different from `by` variables, in particular you can use `by` in `PROC MEANS` of course, but it is substantially slower (as much as 50% slower in some of my tests).  Nonetheless that's an interesting comparison - in particular as there are cases where `proc means` is the fastest way to sort certain kinds of datasets.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere Proc Sort and Proc Means have the same internal memory model, @Joe, unfortunately, I don't remember where.